# Resumable Download Google Drive API V3 no Work

Tags: vb.net, download, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to perform a partial download of a file using the google drive api, but I get the whole file, could anyone help me to solve this problem, thanks.

```
 Dim Credenciais = Autenticar()
    Using Servico = AbrirServico(Credenciais)

        Dim file_id As String = "0B8k2FSDvQmj7REJXeURxblFBY00"
        Dim file_name As String = "Test.rar"

        Dim Request = Servico.Files.[Get](file_id)

        Using stream As New System.IO.FileStream(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\downloads\" & file_name, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)

            AddHandler Request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged, AddressOf DownloadProgress

            Request.CreateRequest.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=500-5000")
            Request.Download(stream)

        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: this might help https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#partial_download

Comment: I've been studying this page for days, I'm not sure if I'm assigning the header values the right way, I still can not get it to work.